# How to display the record with the highest value?

Tags: python, data-science

I'm new to python and would like to know how do I display the record with the highest value.

I already figured out how to display the largest value, but I want to display the value concatenated with name(id).

For now, I did the following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('datasets/kc_house_data.csv')
#what is the most expensive house (highest sale value)
print(max(data['price']))
```

That way it's only displaying the value, I want to display the record.

I also tried as follows:

```
print(data[['id', 'price']].sort_values('price', ascending=False).head(1))
```

This way it returned the name and value correctly, but I believe there is some way to do this using the max() function.

Can someone help me?

Comment: try: `data[data['price']==data['price'].max()]`

Comment: Thanks!! I did like this: print(data['id'][data['price']==data['price'].max()])
That way I was able to display only the id!

Comment: Try idxmax instead of max.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can do that with:

```
 data['id'][data['price']==data['price'].max()]
```

using the `max` function as needed.